# Died kernel when running tabula

Tags: python, java, pdf, jupyter-notebook, tabula

I'm running tabula.read_pdf function on Jupyter Notebook. It keeps telling me died kernel. Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you so much!

I tried to install the package on jupyter notebook, and install java on conda prompt. I was trying to extract dataframe from pdf

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the function read_pdf() which is based on Tabula and therefore Java. There is an issue with the access of java within Python when calling this function. You have to uninstall the Jpype1 module as follows :

```
pip uninstall JPype1
```